# sed command not working properly on ubuntu

Tags: sed

I have one file named `config_3_setConfigPW.ldif? containing the following line:

```
{pass}
```

on terminal, I used following commands

```
SLAPPASSWD=Pwd&0011   
sed -i "s@{pass}@$SLAPPASSWD@" config_3_setConfigPW.ldif
```

It should replace `{pass}` to `Pwd&0011` but it generates `Pwd{pass}0011`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the SLAPPASSWD shell variable is expanded before sed sees it.  So sed sees:

```
sed -i "s@{pass}@Pwd&0011@" config_3_setConfigPW.ldif
```

When an "&" is on the right hand side of a pattern it means "copy the matched input", and in your case the matched input is "{pass}".

The real problem is that you would have to escape all the special characters that might arise in SLAPPASSWD, to prevent sed doing this.  For example, if you had character "@" in the password, sed would think it was the end of the substitute command, and give a syntax error.

Because of this, I wouldn't use sed for this.  You could try gawk or perl?

eg, this will print out the modified file in awk (though it still assumes that SLAPPASSWD contains no " character

```
awk -F \{pass\} ' { print  $1"'${SLAPPASSWD}'"$2 } ' config_3_setConfigPW.ldif
```

Comment: You're on the right track by using awk but you're using very error-prone syntax. The correct syntax for your suggested approach be `awk -F '{pass}' -v new="$SLAPPASSWD" ' { print  $1 new $2 } '`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because`$SLAPPASSWD` contains the character sequences `&` which is a metacharacter used by `sed` and evaluates to the matched text in the `s` command. Meaning:

```
sed 's/{pass}/match: &/' <<< '{pass}'
```

would give you:

```
match: {pass}
```

---

A time ago I've asked this question: ["Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed). Answers there show how to reliably escape the password before using it as the replacement part:

```
pwd="Pwd&0011"
pwdEscaped="$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$pwd")"

# Now you can safely pass $pwd to sed
sed -i "s/{pass}/$pwdEscaped/" config_3_setConfigPW.ldif
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that sed NEVER operates on strings. The thing sed searches for is a regexp and the thing it replaces it with is string-like but has some metacharacters you need to be aware of, e.g. `&` or `\<number>`, and all of it needs to avoid using the sed delimiters, `/` typically.

If you want to operate on strings you need to use awk:

```
awk -v old="{pass}" -v new="$SLAPPASSWD" 's=index($0,old){ $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' file
```

Even the above would need tweaked if old or new contained escape characters.